# 404 Redirect is not working

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

In my htaccess file my ErrorDocument 404 statement is not redirecting to index.php. Instead, i'm getting a regular 404 error. This is a regular apache installation.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Poor you!  I really hope you get this sorted out

Comment: Which browser are you using to test this?

Comment: Do you know whether you have mod_rewrite enabled (you can check with `echo phpinfo()`)? Also, what do you mean by "regular 404". Do you mean Apache's 404 or CI's?

Comment: Try with a different browser. Some browsers won't show the content of the response if they get certain status codes (say, 404 instead of 200). Also, is mod_rewrite enabled or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted. I went with a custom error handling router in Code Igniter and skipped the .htaccess file. I didn't have direct access to the clients server so I made the changes on my own and gave them a standard .htaccess file for CI. It just made my life simpler to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

Need more information here. Are getting CodeIgniter's 404 or Apache's 404?

If you're getting CodeIgniter's 404, it's working as expected.

Comment: You're redirecting to /index.php, but is that where index.php lives? In the doc root? Or are you working in a subfolder?